# meaning of 'among others'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The document as it was finally approved set forth the essential
>   principles of freedom and equality for everyone-regardless of sex,
>   race, color, or other status. It also asserted a number of fundamental
>   human rights, including **among others** the right to work, the right to
>   rest and leisure, and the right to education.

What does among others mean? Does this mean other people? or other principles stated in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example

> **amoung others**

is usually used when *explicitly* mentioning *some, but not all, things*, the ones ***not mentioned*** are *amoung the others*.

The ones explicitly mentioned are

> the right to work
>   the right to rest and leisure
>   the right to education

Among the others not explicitly mentioned, might be

> the right to a good meal
>   the right to restful sleep
>   the right to choose a spouse